# JQuery: if element does not contain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a statement along the lines of: 'if given element *does not* contain the following text, do something'.

I have tried using `:contains` as such:

```
var openingHours = $('.opening-listing:nth-child(' + new Date().getDay() + ')');
if($(openingHours + ':contains("Closed")').length > 0){
 //Do something
}
```

But am getting syntax errors.

Would anyone know what I've done wrong here, or if there is a better way of going about this?

Comment: What kind of element is openingHours?

Comment: @BlueBoy a div containing a few spans with text

Comment: What syntax error are you getting? Also can you check if you are getting anything in openingHours var before the if condition?

Comment: You could try if($(openingHours).text().indexOf("Closed") >= 0){ but it's kind of hacky

Comment: What's wrong with checking using the already existing `indexOf` on the `innerHTML`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`openingHours` is a jQuery object, not a `css` selector. You can use `.text()`, `.indexOf()`, which `:contains()` uses internally

```
if (openingHours.text().indexOf("Closed") === -1) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:not()` CSS selector.

```
var openingHours = $('.opening-listing:nth-child(' + new Date().getDay() + ')');
if($(openingHours).find(':not(:contains("Closed"))').length > 0){
 //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They way I understand your question is that; you have an HTML element with some content (text or number). And you want to use that content in decision making such as if-statement.

Here is an example of the code I made in repl.it, [click here](https://repl.it/GxMU/19).

I give each element a unique id name, so that I can call it in JavaScript for decision-making. Then I add onClick which invokes a function in JavaScript.

```
 <form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Your name">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" onClick="getName()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Next step is to use document.getElementById(tagName).value which receives the content you have written in the inputfield after you click on submit button. And set the value into a next variable instead of copying the whole line of code. Last but not least, I have also added an example if you have jQuery library, I prefer using jQuery approach because it is less code and easier to understand for beginners.

```
function getName(){
      // Gets the value from HTML and inserts the result in new variable called inputName
      var inputName = document.getElementById("inputName").value;

      // This works only if you have jQuery library included in html part 
      //var inputName = $("#inputName").val();

      // If-statement
      if(inputName === "Peter"){
        alert("Name is = " + inputName);
      } else if(inputName === "Jacob"){
        alert("Name is = " + inputName);
      }
    }
```

I hope this gives you different perspective on how to solve your problem. Good luck!